# In Scala, how to do in shell "cat <file> | ssh user@host "aws s3 cp - s3://"?

Tags: scala, ssh

What is the best way to achieve below in scala?

```
cat <file> | ssh user@host "aws s3 cp - s3://"
```

We need to go through a particular bastion host which has the privilege to upload to S3. We can easily do this in shell but not sure what is the best way to do in Scala. Is there any particular library I should use instead of using SEQ()?

I checked scala-ssh but it seems that you can't use pipe input to SSH. And also, we don't want to do "scp and then aws cp" since it will be two hops.

Please advise me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  import sys.process._

  val command = "cat  <file>" #| """ssh user@host "aws s3 cp - s3://"""

  command.!
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I would consider this similar to SEQ() method since it is calling external commands. Is there any java library or scala library that can read from input stream and use the stream in ssh command?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [Cable](https://github.com/zhongwm/cable) to do this

As an example, we pipe data to remote host tasks like this:

```scala
import cable.zssh.TypeDef._
import HostConnS._
import cable.zssh.Zssh._

val putFileI = Action("my-server", action = scriptIO("cat -", new File("My file.txt")))
val putStringI = Action("my-server", username = Some("user1"), action = scriptIO("cat -", "String data"))
val putStream = Action("my-server", action = scriptIO("cat -", inputStream))
```

Moreover, in the above task constructions, we just name the host to connect to, in this case
"my-server", and leave the username, password, or private key omitted, these default to the
current system user and private key, which is just like the way SSH does, if you get your machine's
ssh-copy-id -ish thing configured, indeed you can just name the host to connect to.

More info:

https://github.com/zhongwm/cable/blob/master/wiki/Piping_streams_to_remote_task.md